# Magento2.3.0 How to add custom attachment for pdf in admin side product edit page?

Tags: admin-panel, custom-attributes, magento2.3.0

I am using magneto2.3.0 and I already free plugin use for custom attachment for product edit page but there PDF attached after product not save it.

Issues come in magneto2.3.0 version if anyone tries to this version please reply to me just simple PDF file added in product edit page admin side after saving the product.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new attribute in your product. With this is not necessary use any plugin.

```
 <?php

namespace Vendor\Catalog\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface {

private $eavSetupFactory;
private $attributeSetFactory;
private $attributeSet;
private $categorySetupFactory;  

public function __construct(
    Config $eavConfig,
    EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
    AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
    CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory,
    AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepositoryInterface
    ) {
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory; 
    $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepositoryInterface;
    $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory; 
} 

public function upgrade(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
    $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.13', '<')) {

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'your_attr_name');

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'your_attr_name', [
            'group' => 'Ficha Técnica',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Attr Name',
            'input' => 'file',
            'backend' => 'Vendor\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\FileUpload',
            'frontend' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'sort_order' => 3
            ]);

    }

}
```

}

The backend class will save this attribute. Vendor/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/FileUpload.php

```
namespace Vendor\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class FileUpload extends AbstractBackend {

    protected $_uploaderFactory;

    protected $_filesystem;

    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;

    protected $_logger;

    protected $_file;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, Filesystem $filesystem, UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory, File $file)
    {
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_file = $file;
    }

    public function afterSave($object)
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();

        $value = $object->getData($attributeCode);
        $deleteValue = $object->getData($attributeCode . '_delete');

        $this->prepareFiles($attributeCode);

        // Delete old image or unset
        if ((($value ?? false) && ($_FILES[$attributeCode]['tmp_name'] ?? false)) || 
            (($value ?? false) && ($deleteValue ?? false))
        ) {
            try {
                $this->deleteFile($value);
                $object->setData($attributeCode, null);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new FrameworkException($e->getMessage());
            }

        }

        if ($_FILES[$attributeCode]['tmp_name'] ?? false) {
            try {
                $file = $this->saveFile($attributeCode);
                $object->setData($attributeCode, $file['file']);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new FrameworkException($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $attributeCode);

        return parent::afterSave($object);
    }

    private function prepareFiles($attributeCode)
    {
        if ($_FILES['product'] ?? false) {
            foreach($_FILES['product'] as $value => $key) {
                if ($key[$attributeCode] ?? false) {
                    $_FILES[$attributeCode][$value] = $key[$attributeCode];
                    unset($_FILES[$value][$key][$attributeCode]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function saveFile($attributeCode)
    {
        $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath( 'catalog/product/files/' );

        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $attributeCode]);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);

        return $uploader->save($path);
    }

    private function deleteFile($fileName)
    {
        $basePath = 'catalog/product/files/';

        $imagePath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath($basePath . $fileName);

        if ($this->_file->isExists($imagePath)) {
            $this->_file->deleteFile($imagePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this path vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Attribute we are create FileUpload.php or not? please brief descibe me

Comment: Yes, we need to create this. This module will extend the standard magento-catalog.

Comment: In this file define use and namespace   Vendor/Catalog/Setup/UpgradeData.php please provide full code so easily put it

Comment: I have check it in this path Vendor/Catalog/Setup/UpgradeData.php there other file "CategorySetup.php" open it and check it there code define more than so i think setup file code missing it in your side

Comment: I just updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thank you so much let me check it

Comment: I follow your instruction after check it but not create it custom attribute

Comment: your code put it our app/code/Vendor/Catalog/Setup/UpgradeData.php inside code after all command apply it

Comment: This works, but it only works for one attachment per product. Is there any way to update this with a way to add multiple files per product? 
Also, I've been able to add a tab and show these on the frontend, but I haven't been able to add a label for each file. Is there a way to do that? Thanks